# CakePHP saveAll/saveAssociated issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm a bit confused with the following CakePHP outcome. I included code for two Model and one Controller (stripped out unnecessary stuff).

**Problem: Everything saves correctly. The only issue is the user_id field for the store_users table does not save.**

Anything obvious you can see that I'm doing wrong? I tried with both saveAssociated and saveAll.

**Model/Store.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Store extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User'
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'StoreUser'
    );
}
```

**Model/StoreUser.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class StoreUser extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User',
        'Store'
    );
}
```

**Controller/StoresController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class StoresController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Store');

    public function create() {
        $this->Store->create();
        $storeData = array(
            'Store' => array(
                'title' => 'New Store',
                'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
             ),
             'StoreUser' => array(
                 'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
              )
        );
        if($this->Store->saveAll($storeData) !== false) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
}
```

**Results in DB**

```
stores table:
    id: 1
    title: New Store
    user_id: 1
    ...

store_users table:
    id: 1
    store_id: 1
    user_id: 0
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Because *Store hasMany StoreUser* and not *Store hasOne StoreUser* I must wrap the `user_id` in the supplied data in an array.

**Controller/StoresController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class StoresController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Store');

    public function create() {
        $this->Store->create();
        $storeData = array(
            'Store' => array(
                'title' => 'New Store',
                'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
             ),
             'StoreUser' => array(
                 array(
                     'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                 )
              )
        );
        if($this->Store->saveAll($storeData) !== false) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
}
```